# Solidity uint256[] not returning from a function

Tags: arrays, blockchain, solidity

I have a function that returns an uint256[] from this mapping : `mapping(address => uint256[]) ownerToIds`

but the problem is that when I try to return the array elements it does nothing.

I already tried adding `public` and `view` to function but it didn't change anything.

code: (using remix in binance testnet)

```
mapping(address => uint256[]) ownerToIds;

function getOwnersOwnedTokenIds(address owner) public returns(uint256[] memory){
    return ownerToIds[owner];
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can return values with memory flag, as it is returned from a function. Try only returning the uint256[] without memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want return a specific data for handle it outsite your smart contract, you must use view access modifier. It allows you to extrapolated data from your smart contract.

In your case, you can try to modify your `getOwnersOwnedTokenIds()` function in this way:

```
function getOwnersOwnedTokenIds(address owner) public view returns(uint256[] memory){
  return ownerToIds[owner];
}
```

Example of a working smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {

    mapping(address => uint256[]) ownerToIds;

    constructor() {
        ownerToIds[msg.sender].push(1);
        ownerToIds[msg.sender].push(2);
        ownerToIds[msg.sender].push(3);
        ownerToIds[msg.sender].push(4); 
    }

    function getOwnersOwnedTokenIds(address owner) public view returns(uint256[] memory){
        return ownerToIds[owner];
    }

}
```